# Disambiguate "arity denotation" and "arithmetic division" in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I learned that `&(X.f/1)` denotes the use of the capture operator (`&`) on a function `f`, which is defined inside the module `X`, and that f has arity 1.

I think I understood the semantic of this capturing, but it is the syntax which troubles me.

Looking at just `X.f/1`, this could also be understood as the result of the division of an niladic function `X.f`, by 1.

According to which rule is `/` understood here as a notation for arity instead of a division operator? Does the capture operator introduce a specific syntactic scope, which interprets the slash only as arity denotation?

(To clarify: With *syntacic scope*, I mean something similar in spirit as in shell programming (zsh, bash), where i.e. `((a+b))` is understood due the inclusion inside `((....))` as the addition of the shell variables `a` and `b`, without the need to write ...`$a + $b`...)

So, how does the compiler know, that `/` does not mean division here?

Comment: Short answer: It knows because the definition is not ambiguous. When you will have ambiguous definitions, the compiler will warn you about this and you will be forced to deal with it.

Comment: @Daniel: Why isn't it ambiguous? `X.f/1` **can** mean division after all. How else would you write the division of `X.f`  by `1`? Or am I forced to write `X.f()/1`,  even when `f` does not take parameters?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip: Ah, I see, so `&` imposes a different context than other operators (like for instance the negation operator `-`). Could it be that `&` is not really and "operator", but more like a keyword or an Elixir special form? BTW, if you put this as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Whoops deleted my comment before you replied 

Comment: Elixir is all about the AST. I'm pretty sure that any use of a function capture will cause & to be the root of that branch of the AST, which will cause it to be evaluated in that context. But I'm not familiar enough with the parser to provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the capture operator introduce a specific syntactic scope, which interprets the slash only as arity denotation?

Yes. This actually happens in [here in `:elixir_expand`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.16.1/lib/elixir/src/elixir_expand.erl#L207-L229) where the capture operator is handled, then most of the work gets delegated to [`:elixir_fn.capture/4`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.16.1/lib/elixir/src/elixir_fn.erl#L41).

It is important to note that there is no distinction from a regular division at the AST level (you can confirm it in IEx with `quote do: foo/1` and `quote do: &foo/1`). The compiler will simply interpret it differently when handling the capture.

Here is an example to illustrate the point: consider `&:math.pi/&1`.
This is a valid function, equivalent to `fn x -> :math.pi() / x end`.
Because the first clauses of `:elixir_fn.capture/4` won't match (`A` is not an integer), it will consider `/` as a regular division expression, try to find an `&1` arg (and succeed).

Finally, the error message from an invalid capture explains the logic well:

```elixir
iex> &invalid
error: invalid args for &, expected one of:

 * &Mod.fun/arity to capture a remote function, such as &Enum.map/2
 * &fun/arity to capture a local or imported function, such as &is_atom/1
 * &some_code(&1, ...) containing at least one argument as &1, such as &List.flatten(&1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. I must admit that the details of the code you linked to, are still beyond my understanding. For instance, they use for the matching of the functions always the parameter `Meta`; since it starts with an upper case name, I guess that this must be some module, but I don't see which module would be matched when we do a `&:math.pi/&1`. Nevertheless, I think I understood the general picture.

Comment: @user1934428 That code is Erlang, where variables start with a capital letter (or an underscore).

Comment: Yes `Meta` is just a variable here for the node metadata. Metadata is not very important to understand most of the AST handling. The elixir AST typically has [this structure](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html#the-elixir-ast), `{caller, meta, args}`, you can usually focus on `caller` and `args`. `&:math.pi/&1` is `{:&, _, [{:/, _, [math_pi_ast, {:&, _, [1]}]}]}` (you can use `quote` to check it).